# Should user account be locked after X amount of failed logins?

Tags: sql, authentication, coldfusion, locking, login-attempts

I have almost finished developing my login system and there is one more thing that I'm not sure about. So many debates I found on should the internet about counting invalid logins and locking users account. My system stores user names and passwords (that are salted and hashed) in database. If user enters invalid user name or password I keep track of their `Username`, `Password`, `LoginTime`, `SessionID`, `IP` and `Browser`. Here is example:

```
LoginID   LoginTime                 LoginUN    LoginPW    LoginSessionID    LoginIP     LoginBrowser    
   1    2018-03-15 13:40:25.000     jpapis     test       E72E.cfusion      10.18.1.37  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
  98    2018-03-15 13:48:45.000     mhart      mypass55   E72E.cfusion      10.12.1.87  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
  32    2018-03-15 14:29:14.000     skatre     1167mmB!   378E.cfusion    10.36.1.17    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
```

I'm wondering if I should lock account after X attempts? If so what would be the best practice to do that? Here is one approach that I found:

```
SELECT COUNT(LoginID) AS countID, DATEDIFF(mi,LoginTime,GETDATE ( )) AS TimeElapsed
FROM FailedLogins
WHERE (LoginUN = '#username#' OR LoginSessionID = '#SESSION.sessionid#' OR LoginIP = '#REMOTE_ADDR#')
    AND DATEDIFF(mi,LoginTime,GETDATE ( )) <= 60
GROUP BY LoginID, LoginTime
HAVING COUNT(LoginID) >= 5;
```

Query above will look for `username`, `sessionID` or `IP` address. If either of these it's found in `FailedLogin` table within `60min` and it's greater than 5 I would lock the account. Only problem here is I'm not sure what this would prevent, brute force attack can send way too many attempts in 60min so I'm not sure what would be the benefit of checking failed logins this way. Is there better way to handle failed logins now days? Should I even lock the account? If anyone can provide some thoughts and examples please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Seems better suited to [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=locking+account+failed+login). Did you do a search there? I see a lot of threads on that exact topic...

Comment: @Ageax I have done some research and that's where I found solution above. Still can't decide which way to go and best practice for invalid attempts.

Comment: Please... don't log passwords.  The most likely failure is that somebody is fat-fingering a password or username, which means your log would be a nice target for hackers.  For that matter, why are you implementing your own login?  Using existing libraries or infrastructure would likely provide this out-of-the box.  Beyond that, though, generally you start with _throttling_ login attempts, only letting so many per account per ip through at a time (but usually you want that to be at least partially handled by loadbalancers, or DOS follows).

Comment: Still, given the tone of thread "should I do X, what are the benefits of Y" it sounds more like a question for that audience, as opposed to S.O. which is more focused on "how do I implement X or Y in code"

Comment: I wouldn't just lockout their account. Give them a few failed attempts (5 is good), and then disable the account for 10 minutes or so. If someone is trying to brute force the account, they'll get bored pretty quickly. If it's a legit user, there are already plenty of real-world cases where repeated failed logins results in a short "time-out". And don't log passwords. Just log failed (or successful if you need) logins. Then a simple count on those will tell you if you need to lock them.

Comment: And I agree with Ageax. This is more a question for InfoSec than about ColdFusion.

Comment: `"brute force attack can send way too many attempts in 60min so I'm not sure what would be the benefit of checking failed logins this way"` >> Yes, but if the account is locked out, it won't matter how many attempts they make. If they keep beating on your login system, then you've moved from `invalid login` territory to a `DOS`. Those are handled much differently.

Comment: And since you're here, are you using one salt for all logins or is it per person? If it's just one salt, you're defeating most of the purpose of a salt. A salt simply makes it harder for a bad actor to guess your passwords and pre-compute a dictionary of possible password hashes and it will also significantly reduce the harm of collisions in your hashed passwords. Again, this is a much more appropriate topic for InfoSec.

Comment: That's a business decision.  Talk to your employer.

Comment: And use `<cfqueryparam>`, please! You have 3 fields that can be attacked. OK, maybe 2

Comment: @Shawn I use different salt for each password.

Comment: @DanBracuk I wish they can make decision in this case. Unfortunately for many reasons I have to do that. This system is not payroll/finance but still we store some sensitive data. I'm looking for some reasonable solution that would be a good fit on the long term.

Comment: @JamesAMohler I didn't include that in my code but only `cfqueryparam` is applied on the `username` field since that comes from the user. Other two are system variables.

Comment: @espresso_coffee - You should still use it for the other variables. Aside from SQL Injection protection it also provides extra type checking and can improve database performance. Plus, if the source of those variables ever changes, the query will still be safe.

Comment: Just note that `cfqueryparam` won't make your application completely safe. You should still sanitize anything that can possibly come from someone or something other than you.

Comment: @Shawn Sanitizing user name and password can be tricky. Also both of these fields are created for the users. They can't create account for them self.

Comment: One other thing you want to look out for is that someone shouldn't be able to DOS your site by working through your users and locking all of the accounts out. In fact, a failed login shouldn't even indicate if it was the username or password that failed. This is one of the reasons this would be much better suited on the InfoSec site. Logins are a somewhat complex discussion that will require multiple levels of protection to properly handle.

Comment: @espresso_coffee If the system creates the initial un/pw, you don't have to worry about that, but I would assume that the user would eventually have to use that un/pw. THAT'S where you sanitize. Also, a site-generated password should be extremely temporary and require a reset on first login. Again, authentication (even without getting to authorization) can be an extremely complex topic.

Comment: @Shawn Everything you mentioned in your previous comment I already completed in my system. Sanitizing username & password, creating temporary password and forcing it to be changed on the first login. Like I mentioned last step is to handle incorrect passwords and prevent multiple tries.

Comment: @espresso_coffee And I would also recommend that you take a look at Troy Hunt's https://haveibeenpwned.com/passwords API. I'm not usually a fan of blacklisting (prefer whitelisting), but this is one case where it makes complete sense.

Comment: *Just note that cfqueryparam won't make your application completely safe*  Very true.  I should have said "if the variable source changes, the query won't be immediately vulnerable to simple sql injection". Though If you're doing risky stuff like using dynamic sql, not even cfqueryparam is going to help you....

Comment: I wouldn't log the password for a failed attempt. Like someone previously stated, that could be a goldmine for a bad actor to grab. For failed attempts, I wouldn't log more than time, user IP, and attempted username. If you have a specific user with multiple bad logins, block that user. If you have an IP with multiple username bad attempts, you need to push it higher and block that IP from even accessing your site. Then have some SQL job that will clean up your database periodically. A table with a bazillion failed attempts can DOS you, too.

Comment: @Ageax I love `cfqueryparam`. But what it does and doesn't do could quickly turn into a massive discussion. :-)

Comment: @Shawn - True.  Adding a disclaimer was a knee jerk reaction on my part after re-reading my own comment.  I normally avoid using absolutes phrases like that, lest some people take it to mean "cfqueryparam protects me from everything!" (which yes .. has happened) ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Agree with @Ageax on checking [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=locking%20account%20failed%20login).

> I'm not sure that I need this kind of security check in my system.

Yes, you do. You always do. It's those that don't that often appear on the news.

Some best practices

- Lock account after X number of failed logins.
- Keep a record of Y past passwords (hashed, not plain text). When someone updates their password, check the new one against the old ones so they can't reuse recent passwords (compare hashes).
- Monitor failed attempts past X to determine if you need to block IP addresses if failed attempts become excessive.
- When a user's login fails, never tell them if it was specifically the user name or the password that was incorrect. You're just helping hackers progress faster.

Do some reading on the other site and see what else is recommended.

Comment: To note, I wouldn't keep the actual past password, but the hash of that password. Never, ever, ever store plaintext passwords. Unless you want to appear on the news. :-)

Comment: @Shawn That's what I meant by "compare hashes", but I've updated to clarify. I should have been more explicit in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't directed at you so much as a future reader of this post. I've read you long enough to know that you don't like being on the news. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You must create a password lockout system only for **payed or premium accounts, or if the website you or someone else owns is extremely popular (More than 100,000 annual viewers)**, as they are most valued, and most likely to be attacked. If you expect such a volume of people, then it is best practice to implement this. You can see many large corporations doing this practice, Google locks people out of accounts because they can contain money like in Google Play Store Credits or Android Pay wallets. The same goes for Minecraft accounts, Netflix accounts, etc. The algorithm behind this is something like this :

```
if(md5($password)==$loginrow['login'])
{
   //Do your login sequence here
}
else
{
  if($loginrow['AttemptsInPastFifteenMinutes']>=15)
  {
     mysqli_query($dbconnect,'CREATE EVENT reset ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 MINUTE DO UPDATE ' .$loginrow['user']. 'set AttemptsInPastFifteenMinutes = 0');
     echo '<script>alert("You have typed in invalid passwords too many times. Please try again later.");</script>';
  }
  else
  {
     mysqli_query($dbconnect,'UPDATE logins SET AttemptsInPastFifteenMinutes=' .($loginrow['AttemptsInPastFifteenMinutes'] + 1). ' WHERE user=' .$loginrow['user']');
     echo '<script>alert("Invalid username or password");</script>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Why just paid or premium accounts? I completely agree that the type of information you store affects your level of security, but any time you see an excessive amount of failed logins, it's not likely to be legit traffic. You kinda have an obligation to protect your users, too. And that should mean doing at least something to prevent a baddy from abusing your users' information. Lockouts are easily implemented, and are a very simple way to make your baddy move on to his next target.

Comment: Besides, since most people seem to reuse login credentials across many sites, it could very well be YOUR stolen database that allows the baddy to break into Google's sites.

Comment: I'm not sure that I need this kind of security check in my system. We do not have that amount of traffic. Also I have to mention that only Administrators can create accounts for users in their company. So we have restricted access to this system. We do store some sensitive data but we do not have any money transactions in the system.